# Binary XML file - error inflating class fragment

Tags: java, android

I am getting an error saying " Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class fragment". I tried searching on here and found some solutions but they haven't worked, any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

I was using this example of Java code to implement this for the app. 
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/start

I am fairly new to Android Programming with Java, I started a year ago using Kotlin and am doing this in Java to help a friend.

Thanks in advance

MapActivity

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MapActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);

        SupportMapFragment mapFragment =
                (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(0, 0)).title("Marker"));
    }

}
```

StackTrace:

```
06-25 16:32:26.142 31234-31234/com.example.miftekhar.androidapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.miftekhar.androidapp, PID: 31234
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.miftekhar.androidapp/com.example.jakub.androidapp.MapActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class fragment
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2793)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2864)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1567)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6523)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:942)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:832)
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class fragment
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class fragment
 Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: API key not found.  Check that <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" android:value="your API key"/> is in the <application> element of AndroidManifest.xml
    at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.drd.q.b(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesb@12685025@12.6.85 (040408-197041431):40)
    at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.auth.e.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesb@12685025@12.6.85 (040408-197041431):11)
    at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.e.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesb@12685025@12.6.85 (040408-197041431):4)
    at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.b.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesb@12685025@12.6.85 (040408-197041431):24)
    at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.CreatorImpl.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesb@12685025@12.6.85 (040408-197041431):69)
    at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.CreatorImpl.newMapFragmentDelegate(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesb@12685025@12.6.85 (040408-197041431):32)
    at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.i.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesb@12685025@12.6.85 (040408-197041431):31)
    at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:499)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.maps.zza.transactAndReadException(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.zzf.zzc(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$zzb.zzc(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$zzb.createDelegate(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.DeferredLifecycleHelper.zza(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.DeferredLifecycleHelper.onInflate(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.onInflate(Unknown Source)
    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.onInflate(Fragment.java:1302)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:3714)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:114)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.dispatchFragmentsOnCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:374)
    at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityApi14.onCreateView(BaseFragmentActivityApi14.java:39)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:68)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:788)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:738)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:869)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:832)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:518)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:426)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:377)
    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:454)
    at com.android.internal.policy.HwPhoneWindow.setContentView(HwPhoneWindow.java:280)
    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2515)
    at com.example.jakub.androidapp.MapActivity.onCreate(MapActivity.java:16)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6910)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1123)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2746)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2864)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1567)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6523)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:942)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:832)
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:screenOrientation="landscape">
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Gradle:

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.miftekhar.androidapp"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.5'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

Comment: `API key not found.  Check that <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" android:value="your API key"/> is in the <application> element of AndroidManifest.xml` - Have you added your Google Maps API key to your manifest like the error suggests?

Answer (score 1):

As the log says :

```
 Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: API key not found.  Check that <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" android:value="your API key"/> is in the <application> element of AndroidManifest.xml
```

You need to add the Google API key in your `manifest` file like :

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" 
        android:value="your API key"/>
```

Comment: Thanks,  I did have that line just in the wrong place. Such a rookie move! All works now, Have a great day!

Answer (score 1):

This is the key line of the error

> API key not found.  Check that `<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" android:value="your API key"/>` is in the `<application>` element of AndroidManifest.xml

So firstly you need to sign up for an API key from the [Google Maps Platform](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/signup) website. You then need to add this API key to `AndroidManifest.xml` inside the `<application>` tag like so:

```
<manifest ... >
    ...
    <application ...>
        ...
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" android:value="API_KEY"/>
        ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Where `API_KEY` is the key you received from the Google Maps Platform website.

Comment: Thanks,  I did have that line just in the wrong place. Such a rookie move! All works now, Have a great day!

Comment: No worries, if either of mine or Bubu's answers have helped then please click the ✔ next to one of them to mark the question as solved.